# In Ruby, what is an elegant line that can generate a random string with 8 characters?

Tags: ruby

There is a line in Rails Tutorial:

```
('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0..7].join
```

that can generate `"zwnrfxte"`, but it is not using the same characters again.  What is an elegant line that can?  And one that can use both a..z and A..Z ?

Comment: Just replacing `('a'..'z').to_a` with `('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a` will be the easiest solution.

Comment: characters need to be able to repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a 
0.upto(7).map{|x| a[ rand( a.size ) ] }
```

Comment: this one `8.times.map{a[rand(a.size)]}.join` good too... tried in Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: This is not a 1 liner... just sayin :P

Answer (score 3):

```
letters = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
rand_string = (0..7).inject(""){|s| s << letters.sample}
```

or one liner:

```
(0..7).inject(""){|s| s << (('a'..'z').to_a+('A'..'Z').to_a).sample}
```

This will use the same character(if it was chosen) and it has a-zA-Z.

Using [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000285)

Comment: Or as a one liner (0..7).map{('a'..'z').to_a.concat(('A'..'Z').to_a).sample}.join

Comment: @mike..inject has 2 parameters in the block, right? u have given 1 only.

Comment: The 1 liner gives 9 chars because the `..` is inclusive.

Comment: @rubyprince, yea that was intentional. I wanted to use inject/reduce for its "reduce into a string" so I didn't have to use join

Answer (score 3):

In 1.9 this can be done in a pretty clean way:

```
>> 8.times.map { [*?a..?z,*?A..?Z].sample }.join #=> "kmQQvuPd"
```

Characters will get repeated as this example with a smaller character range shows:

```
>> 8.times.map { [*?a..?c,*?A..?C].sample }.join #=> "CaACAaBa"
```

You probably want to store the letters array in separate variable though:

```
>> letters = [*?a..?z,*?A..?Z] #=> ["A", "B", "C", ...]
>> 8.times.map { letters.sample }.join #=> "HBKKbnzx"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Mix in Entropy for Cryptographically Secure Randomness

```
File.open('/dev/random', 'r') { |f| f.sysread(8).tr "\0-\377", "a-zA-Z"*5 }
```

(At least for Linux/Unix/Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the hell of it here are some more:

```
8.times.map {(rand(26) + (rand > 0.5 ? 65 : 97)).chr}.join
 => "JnFHpIqb"

8.times.map {((r = rand(26)) > 13 ? r + 65 : r + 97).chr}.join
 => "PQYciXcg"
```

both of these can be adapted to use inject:

```
8.times.inject("") {|s| s += (rand(26) + (rand > 0.5 ? 65 : 97)).chr}
 => "WFkVqgeG"

8.times.inject("") {|s| s += ((r = rand(26)) > 13 ? r + 65 : r+ 97).chr}
 => "faQnScmd"
```